# How to set jpeg quality using imagemin-cli?

Tags: npm-scripts, imagemin

I am trying to use imagemin to compress images in an npm task. I am able to get the image slightly compressed using:

```
imagemin src/images/*.jpg -o dist/images --plugin=jpegtran
```

but I can't find anything in the imagemin-cli docs on how to pass an option to set the amount of compression.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [jpegtran](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-jpegtran) plugin which uses lossless algorithms. That means you can't do much to adjust the compression, as the algorithms behind it are unable reduce the quality of the image.

If you want more compression you have to use lossy compression plugins, such as [jpeg-recompress](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-jpeg-recompress) or [jpegoptim](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-jpegoptim).

Comment: Came here via Google search, so I thought I'd add my solution. Following on @MikaS suggestion, here's an example using jpegoptim: `imagemin --plugin.jpegoptim.progressive=true --plugin.jpegoptim.max=70 *.jpg --out-dir=./out`